# Django QuerySet Any

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get a queryset of all books that are currently in Library (the dateReturn of a currently rent is set to null). 
I'm new to python and i don't know how to do subqueries in django.
In other words in want to filter *every* related object field on a condition, if only one *related-object* doesn't match to this condition the *object* must not be returned

*models.py*

```
class Book(models.Model):
    cod = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    .....


class Rent(models.Model):
    dateRent = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    dateReturn = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(modelsBook.Book, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="rent")
    .....
```

P.S:
I need this subquery for display book currently not render in a choiceField

*forms.py*

```
class RentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    __pk=None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        super(RentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta():
        model = models.Rent
        fields = ('book', 'student')      
        labels = {
            'book' : _('Libro'),
            'student' : _('Studente'),
        }
        widgets = {

            'book': queryset,
.....
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can filter objects through the related_name.

```
class RentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    __pk=None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        super(RentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['book'].queryset = Book.objects.exclude(rent__dateReturn__isnull=True)
   ...
```